# Closing BufferedReader and BufferedWriter when killing Java process

Tags: java

I have a java program that reads logging information whilst it's being updated and writes the filtered data to a new file. When I execute this as a jar it will run until I kill the process.

How can I make sure that when I kill this process that I close BufferedReader and BufferedWriter to prevent memory leaks?

I have tried using try...finally block methods as suggested by others but this closes the stream whilst the program is still running. Thanks in advance.

FileWatcher.java

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.io.*

public class FileWatcher implements Runnable
{
  boolean running = true;
  File file;
  BufferedReader reader;
  BufferedWriter writer;
  String pathToLog, pathToOutput;

  public FileWatcher(String pathToLog, String pathToOutput)
  {
    this.pathToLog = pathToLog;
    this.pathToOutput = pathToOutput;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      file = new File(pathToOutput);
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToLog));
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToOutput));

      if (!file.exists())
      {
        file.createNewFile();
      }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String line = null;

    System.out.println("Running...");
    while (running)
    {
      try
      {
        /* For each packet logged */
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
          line = reader.readLine(); //Analyse text in line

          /* If no text then break */
          if (line == null)
          {
            break;
          }

          /* If the line begins with valid IP address then break to find Src and Dest IP */
          if (line.startsWith("192", 22))
          {
            break;
          }
        }

        /* If line is not null then filter out the Source IP and Destination IP */
        if (line != null)
        {
          int lastIndexOfSrcIP = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line, ":", 3); // Position to stop reading Source IP
          int firstIndexOfDestIP = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line, ">", 1) + 2; // Position to start reading Destination IP
          int lastIndexOfDestIP = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(line, ":", 4); // Position to stop reading Destination IP

          String sourceIP = line.substring(22, lastIndexOfSrcIP); // Source IP
          String destinationIP = line.substring(firstIndexOfDestIP, lastIndexOfDestIP); // Destination IP

          /* Check if Source IP is the IP address of the node  we are running Snort on
           * if so then don't append to malicious clients file */
          if (!(sourceIP.equals("192.168.7.5")))
          {
            //If Source IP is not in file then add it
            if (!(FileUtils.readFileToString(file).contains(sourceIP)))
            {
              writer.write(sourceIP + "\n");
              writer.flush();
            }

            System.out.println(sourceIP + "\t" + destinationIP);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          //Sleep whilst there are no new logging alert information
          try
          {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
            running = false;
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Daemon
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String pathToLog = args[0];
    String pathToOutput = args[1];

    Thread daemon = new Thread(new FileWatcher(pathToLog, pathToOutput));
    daemon.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use try-with-resources feature of Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, I would create the file in the constructor, this allows you code to fail fast and let the caller know this is not going to work.

I would then have a try/finally block which wraps all the code, something like

```
public void run() {
    try {
        run0();
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("Process dying");
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close all resources
    }
}

private void run0() throws Stuff... {
    // does the real work
}
```

> How can I make sure that when I kill this process that I close BufferedReader and BufferedWriter to prevent memory leaks?

When you kill a process, the OS will reclaim all the processes resources so you can't get a memory leak not matter how you code it.  The only resource leak you can get is unwanted temporary files being left behind.

BTW

- When you call FileWriter, it will create a new file or truncate as required.  There is no point checking if the file still exists because even if it had been deleted (which is extremely unlikely) , you would not be using the one you just created.
- I wouldn't create a new thread just at the end of main as this gains you nothing.
- Also I would only call a thread `daemon` if it is a daemon thread.  Giving it a misleading name could be confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Could you explain what you mean by not creating a new thread at the end of main? I don't quite understand what you mean by that

Comment: @Balamory You are replacing your main thread with one you just started.  You could just have your main method call a method in FileWatcher.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7 or later, you can use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to declare your readers / writers, and they should close automatically when you kill the process.

In your example it would look like this:

```
try(reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToLog));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToOutput));) {
        ...
}
```

Comment: `file` is not closable.